# Java copy files to a directory with a certain prefix

Tags: java, copy, prefix

I try to make a java code that will search for every directory that is starting with "test-" and then will copy files to it.

Currently i have this as code

```
                File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test");
            File[] foundFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.startsWith("test-");
```

But, i can't figure out how to let it now copy files to the directories with that as prefix..

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to do something like:

```
   for(File cpy:listOfFilesToCopy){
        for(File dir:foundFiles){
            Files.copy(cpy,dir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whoops, the third line should be `Files.copy(cpy.toPath(),dir.toPath().resolve(cpy.toPath().getFileName());` Of course, there are cleaner ways to do this; this is just very compact.